# Mysql query not giving expected results on group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, case-when

I have queue_log table with multiple records for single call record with unique column call_id repeated for single call number of rows.

I have below query.

```
select  case when verb="did"  then data1 end as did, 
        case   when verb='CONNECT' then "Answered" else "Missed" end as status,     
        queue,verb,     
        case when verb in ('connect') then agent end as agent 
from queue_log 
where created between '2019-09-01' and '2019-09-09'  
group by call_id 
having verb in ('did','connect','enterqueue','completecaller','completeagent','abandon','exitwithtimeout');
```

let explain bit more. 
If I have a call in queue_log it has one record with verb=did and second verb=connect and then third with verb in ('completecaller','completeagent') and call_id same for all rows.

If in any row there is verb connect then this call is answered else Abandon.

Above query return all abandon calls. while there are answered calls also.

Below is sample data.

$

```
+-------+-----+------------+------------------+-------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------+------+----------+------------------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+---------------------+
| id    | idd | time_id    | call_id          | queue | verb           | queuename | agent          | event | data | data1    | data2            | data3 | data4 | data5 | partition | created             |
+-------+-----+------------+------------------+-------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------+------+----------+------------------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+---------------------+
| 41972 |   0 | 1567386039 | 1567386027.11981 | 4001  | DID            |           | NONE           |       |      | 63897811 |                  |       |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:00:39 |
| 41973 |   0 | 1567386039 | 1567386027.11981 | 4001  | ENTERQUEUE     |           | NONE           |       |      |          | 63038768         | 1     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:00:39 |
| 41974 |   0 | 1567386049 | 1567386027.11981 | 4001  | CONNECT        |           | SIP/135        |       |      | 10       | 1567386039.11982 | 10    |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:00:50 |
| 41975 |   0 | 1567386095 | 1567386027.11981 | 4001  | COMPLETEAGENT  |           | SIP/135        |       |      | 10       | 46               | 1     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:01:35 |
| 41976 |   0 | 1567386104 | 1567386092.11985 | 4003  | DID            |           | NONE           |       |      | 63897815 |                  |       |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:01:44 |
| 41977 |   0 | 1567386104 | 1567386092.11985 | 4003  | ENTERQUEUE     |           | NONE           |       |      |          | 63045831         | 1     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:01:44 |
| 41978 |   0 | 1567386107 | 1567386095.11986 | 4004  | DID            |           | NONE           |       |      | 63897817 |                  |       |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:01:47 |
| 41979 |   0 | 1567386107 | 1567386095.11986 | 4004  | ENTERQUEUE     |           | NONE           |       |      |          | 67379922         | 1     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:01:47 |
| 41980 |   0 | 1567386109 | 1567386092.11985 | 4003  | CONNECT        |           | Christine Nah  |       |      | 5        | 1567386104.11987 | 4     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:01:49 |
| 41981 |   0 | 1567386116 | 1567386095.11986 | 4004  | CONNECT        |           | Helen Ang      |       |      | 9        | 1567386107.11990 | 9     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:01:56 |
| 41982 |   0 | 1567386147 | 1567386095.11986 | 4004  | COMPLETEAGENT  |           | Helen Ang      |       |      | 9        | 31               | 1     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:02:27 |
| 41983 |   0 | 1567386155 | 1567386092.11985 | 4003  | COMPLETECALLER |           | Christine Nah  |       |      | 5        | 46               | 1     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:02:35 |
| 41984 |   0 | 1567386254 | 1567386242.11999 | 4002  | DID            |           | NONE           |       |      | 63897813 |                  |       |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:04:14 |
| 41985 |   0 | 1567386254 | 1567386242.11999 | 4002  | ENTERQUEUE     |           | NONE           |       |      |          | 66438001         | 1     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:04:14 |
| 41986 |   0 | 1567386255 | 1567386243.12000 | 4002  | DID            |           | NONE           |       |      | 63897813 |                  |       |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:04:15 |
| 41987 |   0 | 1567386255 | 1567386243.12000 | 4002  | ENTERQUEUE     |           | NONE           |       |      |          | 62168443         | 2     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:04:15 |
| 41988 |   0 | 1567386266 | 1567386242.11999 | 4002  | CONNECT        |           | Catherine Chia |       |      | 12       | 1567386254.12001 | 12    |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:04:26 |
| 41989 |   0 | 1567386270 | 1567386243.12000 | 4002  | RINGNOANSWER   |           | Team 2 142     |       |      | 15000    |                  |       |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:04:30 |
| 41990 |   0 | 1567386279 | 1567386243.12000 | 4002  | CONNECT        |           | Jace Yeo       |       |      | 24       | 1567386275.12007 | 4     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:04:39 |
| 41991 |   0 | 1567386292 | 1567386242.11999 | 4002  | COMPLETEAGENT  |           | Catherine Chia |       |      | 12       | 26               | 1     |       |       | P001      | 2019-09-02 09:04:52 |
+-------+-----+------------+------------------+-------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-------+------+----------+------------------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+---------------------+
```

```
$

and expected results here below
```

```
+------------------+----------+--------+-------+------+-------+
| call_id          | did      | status | queue | verb | agent |
+------------------+----------+--------+-------+------+-------+
| 1567386027.11981 | 63897811 | Missed | 4001  | DID  | NULL  |
| 1567386092.11985 | 63897815 | Missed | 4003  | DID  | NULL  |
| 1567386095.11986 | 63897817 | Missed | 4004  | DID  | NULL  |
| 1567386242.11999 | 63897813 | Missed | 4002  | DID  | NULL  |
| 1567386243.12000 | 63897813 | Missed | 4002  | DID  | NULL  |
| 1567386337.12010 | 63897813 | Missed | 4002  | DID  | NULL  |
+------------------+----------+--------+-------+------+-------+
```

Comment: could you please add some sample data and your expected output

Comment: added sample data and its results also.

Comment: Group by is intended for use with aggregate functions - you don't have any so the results may be non determinate.please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Why is the having clause there - is there a possibility verb has other than the stated values?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes verbs has other value also.  I am expecting this "        case   when verb='CONNECT' then "Answered" else "Missed" end as status,     
" to recurned Answered for 1567386027.11981 call_id

Comment: why is  1567386027.11981 missed when there is a connect?

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data question and expected result don't match up for me. My guess is that there is always 1 did but there may be multiple connects or no connects. Amending your sample data slightly

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
( id int, idd int, time_id  varchar(20), call_id varchar(30), queue int, verb varchar(20), queuename varchar(20), agent varchar(20),
 event varchar(20), data varchar(20), data1  varchar(20),   data2 varchar(20), data3 varchar(20),
  data4 varchar(20), data5 varchar(20), `partition` varchar(20), created datetime);
insert into t values
( 41972 ,   0 , '1567386039' , '1567386027.11981' , 4001  , 'DID'            ,null , 'NONE'           ,null  ,null , '63897811' , null               ,null   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:00:39') ,
( 41973 ,   0 , '1567386039' , '1567386027.11981' , 4001  , 'ENTERQUEUE'     ,null , 'NONE'           ,null  ,null ,null        , '63038768'         , '1'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:00:39') ,
( 41974 ,   0 , '1567386049' , '1567386027.11981' , 4001  , 'CONNECT'        ,null , 'SIP/135'        ,null  ,null , '10'       , '1567386039.11982' , '10'  ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:00:50') ,
( 41975 ,   0 , '1567386095' , '1567386027.11981' , 4001  , 'COMPLETEAGENT'  ,null , 'SIP/135'        ,null  ,null , '10'       , '46'               , '1'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:01:35') ,
( 41976 ,   0 , '1567386104' , '1567386092.11985' , 4003  , 'DID'            ,null , 'NONE'           ,null  ,null , '63897815' , null               ,null   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:01:44') ,
( 41977 ,   0 , '1567386104' , '1567386092.11985' , 4003  , 'ENTERQUEUE'     ,null , 'NONE'           ,null  ,null ,null        , '63045831'         , '1'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:01:44') ,
( 41978 ,   0 , '1567386107' , '1567386095.11986' , 4004  , 'DID'            ,null , 'NONE'           ,null  ,null , '63897817' , null               ,null   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:01:47') ,
( 41979 ,   0 , '1567386107' , '1567386095.11986' , 4004  , 'ENTERQUEUE'     ,null , 'NONE'           ,null  ,null ,null        , '67379922'         , '1'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:01:47') ,
( 41980 ,   0 , '1567386109' , '1567386092.11985' , 4003  , 'CONNECT'        ,null , 'Christine Nah'  ,null  ,null , '5'        , '1567386104.11987' , '4'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:01:49') ,
( 41981 ,   0 , '1567386116' , '1567386095.11986' , 4004  , 'CONNECT'        ,null , 'Helen Ang'      ,null  ,null , '9'        , '1567386107.11990' , '9'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:01:56') ,
( 41982 ,   0 , '1567386147' , '1567386095.11986' , 4004  , 'COMPLETEAGENT'  ,null , 'Helen Ang'      ,null  ,null , '9'        , '31'               , '1'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:02:27') ,
( 41983 ,   0 , '1567386155' , '1567386092.11985' , 4003  , 'COMPLETECALLER' ,null , 'Christine Nah'  ,null  ,null , '5'        , '46'               , '1'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:02:35') ,
( 41984 ,   0 , '1567386254' , '1567386242.11999' , 4002  , 'DID'            ,null , 'NONE'           ,null  ,null , '63897813' , null               ,null   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:04:14') ,
( 41985 ,   0 , '1567386254' , '1567386242.11999' , 4002  , 'ENTERQUEUE'     ,null , 'NONE'           ,null  ,null ,null        , '66438001'         , '1'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:04:14') ,
( 41986 ,   0 , '1567386255' , '1567386243.12000' , 4002  , 'DID'            ,null , 'NONE'           ,null  ,null , '63897813' , null               ,null   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:04:15') ,
( 41987 ,   0 , '1567386255' , '1567386243.12000' , 4002  , 'ENTERQUEUE'     ,null , 'NONE'           ,null  ,null ,null        , '62168443'         , '2'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:04:15') ,
( 41988 ,   0 , '1567386266' , '1567386242.11999' , 4002  , 'CONNECT'        ,null , 'Catherine Chia' ,null  ,null , '12'       , '1567386254.12001' , '12'  ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:04:26') ,
( 41989 ,   0 , '1567386266' , '1567386242.11999' , 4002  , 'CONNECT'        ,null , 'abc'            ,null  ,null , '12'       , '1567386254.12001' , '12'  ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:04:26') ,
( 41990 ,   0 , '1567386270' , '1567386243.12000' , 4002  , 'RINGNOANSWER'   ,null , 'Team 2 142'     ,null  ,null , '15000'    , null               ,null   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:04:30') ;
#( 41991 ,   0 , '1567386279' , '1567386243.12000' , 4002  , 'CONNECT'        ,null , 'Jace Yeo'       ,null  ,null , '24'       , '1567386275.12007' , '4'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:04:39') ,
#( 41992 ,   0 , '1567386292' , '1567386242.11999' , 4002  , 'COMPLETEAGENT'  ,null , 'Catherine Chia' ,null  ,null , '12'       , '26'               , '1'   ,null   ,null , 'p001'    , '2019-09-02 09:04:52');
```

I have added an additional connect to 1567386242.11999 dropped connect from 1567386243.12000.
This query uses a left join to connect the did to the most recent connect.

```
select t.call_id,t.verb,t.data1,t.queue,
         case when s.verb is null then 'missed'
                else 'Answered'
         end as status,
         case when s.verb is not null then s.agent end as agent
from t
left join 
    (select t.*
    from t
    where id = (select max(id) from t t1 where t1.call_id = t.call_id and t1.verb = 'connect')
    ) s on s.call_id = t.call_id
where t.verb = 'did';

+------------------+------+----------+-------+----------+---------------+
| call_id          | verb | data1    | queue | status   | agent         |
+------------------+------+----------+-------+----------+---------------+
| 1567386027.11981 | DID  | 63897811 |  4001 | Answered | SIP/135       |
| 1567386092.11985 | DID  | 63897815 |  4003 | Answered | Christine Nah |
| 1567386095.11986 | DID  | 63897817 |  4004 | Answered | Helen Ang     |
| 1567386242.11999 | DID  | 63897813 |  4002 | Answered | abc           |
| 1567386243.12000 | DID  | 63897813 |  4002 | missed   | NULL          |
+------------------+------+----------+-------+----------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Which is what I expect given my understanding of the question

Comment: Yes you are right with left join I already have in my actual code and I get my results perfect but query is slow when I add more conditions there. So I thought is  group by call_id would work for me. I am not sure if it will or not.  How ever in above sample data all calls are answered but  the query I write give me all missed. Actually here 
"case   when verb='CONNECT' then "Answered" else "Missed" end as status" 
I am expecting the correct result